# how to communicate the hardware to a realtime controller

Tags: ros, microcontroller, real-time, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys!

Let say that I'm using an action server to request some action to my [realtime controller](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controller_interface). And let say that my hardware (motors and sensors) are being communicating trough a [CANBus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controller_area_network) (not realtime) and I have a node to parse the CAN messages and read/write over the bus.
The question is how to link up the "CAN node-driver" to the controller in a "realtime-safe way". I should use another action client? I should use services?

PS: the message parser communicates with the bus using treads, and currently is not linked with the realtime controller.

thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11691/how-to-communicate-the-hardware-to-a-realtime-controller/) by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 482 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're talking to the controller over a CAN bus, which is not realtime safe.  There's no way to implement a realtime controller in software.

A common way to do a realtime controller is to have the realtime thread and a non-realtime thread which does the external communications, and passes data into the realtime thread in a lock free manner.  You can do this but it's not going to be worth the effort if you're on the other side of a CAN bus.  Realtime requirements are about guaranteeing maximum response times, if there's ever a link which cannot provide those guarantees you cannot continue to be realtime beyond that connection.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on 2011-10-27**:
okay I know that, BUT, I can do guarantee if the bus doesn't gives me the response in X time, the data is no more valid so, do some safety action... this is sotf realtime but it's good enough in my case. tks for the look free trick